# rxjava retrieving the max value from a buffer

Tags: max, buffer, rx-java, reactive-programming

I m using rxjava 1.2.2.

Starting from my List i want to fill a buffer and then to filter the Max item of the buffer the way that, say for example, every 5 seconds just the Max Item filter have to be emitted.

```
Observable<Item> EventEmitter =  Observable.from(itemsList);

Observable<List<Item>> tapBufferEmitter = tapEventEmitter.buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

MathObservable.from(tapBufferEmitter).max(new Comparator<List<Item>>()  {

            @Override
            public int compare(List<Item> o1, List<Item> o2) {
                int m1 =o1.getVal();
                int m2 = o1.getVal();
                if (m1 == m2){
                    return 0;
                } else if (m1 > m2){
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }                           
            }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(executor1))
        .subscribe(s -> {
            System.out.println("Called thread: " +  Thread.currentThread().getId());

            syso.("Max Item is:" + s.getId());
        }, e -> System.out.println(e.getMessage()));
```

But of course the snippet code above doen t work. I don t want to compare 2 list o1 and o2, but i want just to compare the item of the same list.

Is the max operator the right choice? Be aware that i m not comparing integers but Items. Each item is a bead with a fixed field. I want the one with the max value of this field.

How can i select the max from a buffer?
Thanks

Comment: Did you import the libary RxJavaMath as well, because MathObservable is not in the RxJava package.

Comment: yes of course... but i m wondering about the right concatenation of the operators.

Comment: i have edited the question... can you read it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a example, how to use the MathObservable.max operator. Please note that I did use window instead of buffer, because buffer will return a List and window will give me a Observable, which I can reuse with flatMap and MathObservablen. The MathObservable will then calculate the max-value of a given window (observable of 5 elements).

Gradle:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava-math:1.0.0'
```

Window:

```
@Test
public void windowMaxTest() throws Exception {
    Observable<Integer> just = Observable.just(10, 9, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 4, 3);

    Observable<Integer> integerObservable1 = just.window(5)
            .flatMap(integerObservable -> {
                return MathObservable.max(integerObservable);
            });

    TestSubscriber<Integer> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

    integerObservable1.subscribe(testSubscriber);

    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
    testSubscriber.assertValues(10, 8);
}
```

Buffer:

```
@Test
public void bufferMaxTest() throws Exception {
    Observable<Integer> just = Observable.just(10, 9, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6, 8, 4, 3);

    Observable<Integer> integerObservable1 = just.buffer(5)
            .flatMap(integerObservable -> {
                return MathObservable.max(Observable.from(integerObservable));
            });

    TestSubscriber<Integer> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

    integerObservable1.subscribe(testSubscriber);

    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();
    testSubscriber.assertValues(10, 8);
}
```

Custom object::

```
class Item {
    public int value;

    public Item(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

@Test
public void test3214() throws Exception {
    final Item max1 = new Item(3);
    final Item max2 = new Item(6);
    final List<Item> myListOfItem = Arrays.asList(new Item(1), new Item(2), max1, new Item(4), new Item(5), max2);

    Observable<Item> itemObservable1 = Observable
            .from(myListOfItem)
            .buffer(3)
            .flatMap(itemObservable -> {
                Observable<Item> from = Observable.from(itemObservable);

                return MathObservable.from(from)
                        .max((item, t1) -> {
                            return Integer.compare(item.value, t1.value);
                        });
            });

    TestSubscriber<Item> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();

    itemObservable1.subscribe(testSubscriber);

    testSubscriber.awaitTerminalEvent();

    testSubscriber.assertValues(max1, max2);
}
```

Comment: how can i integrate it with a buffer? using the flatmap operator?

Comment: I added buffer-test to my answer.

Comment: sorry again... i m quite new with rx, my input is a List<Item>, so i cannot use the just operator. Cna you update the previous example using a starting list?

Comment: There are several factory methods for it. You could use Observable.from(List<T>) as in bufferMaxTest() in the flatMap. The from method will wrapp the List into an observable which will emit one value by one.

Comment: i tried this code: 
Observable<Item> tapEventEmitter =  Observable.from(myListOfItem);
Observable<Item> itemObservable1 = tapEventEmitter.buffer(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
               .flatMap (itemObservable -> {
                   return MathObservable.max(Observable.from(itemObservable));
               });
But i m getting this
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Observable<Object> to Observable<Item>

Comment: my problem is that i cannot use Integer... i have a list of beans... and i have to extract the bean which has the max value of a fixed field

Comment: I added an example for a custom object. The operator has an overload, which takes an Comparator. I will provide the implemenation as a lambda. You may implement the interface through impelments Comparator. I changed buffer from seconds to a value count. If you will provide code, please post to https://gist.github.com/

Answer (score 0):

in general, *.reduce()* is the standard choice for getting min/max/avg/sum etc.

```
reduce(0, /*return Math.max(lhs, rhs)*/)
```

so the whole operation would be something like this -

```
source.window(/*...*/).flatMap(/*return .reduce(0, /*return Math.max(lhs, rhs)*/))
```

Comment: what about this? .flatMap(/*return .reduce(0, /*return Math.max(lhs, rhs)*/)) i mean return .reduce....

Comment: from original Observable<T> you create Observable<Observable<T>> with .window() operator, then you call .flatMap() on it, and _inside_ .flatMap() operator you return .reduce(0, Math.max()) on .flatMap()'s argument

Comment: but what if my item have a field and i have to emit the item which has the item.getIndex() maximum value?

Comment: my problem is that i cannot use Integer... i have a list of beans... and i have to extract the bean which has the max value of a fixed field

Comment: ah, i see. maybe put a .groupBy() before .reduce() then. your "fixed field" will be the key for GroupedObservable

Comment: or just supply a comparison method to .reduce() (like in the other answer)